# Does dockerd process cpu contain the cpu used by the containers?

Tags: docker, cpu-usage

We have a CentOS machine running Docker with a couple of containers. When running `top`, I see the process `dockerd` which sometimes is using a lot of cpu. Does this cpu utilization contain the cpu usage inside the containers?